# Cypress: Get all elements that have some specific attribute equal to any value

Tags: testing, automation, cypress

I am trying to get all elements that just have a specific attribute, doesn't matter what the attribute value is, and count the number of elements found.

for example get all attribute that has "row-index" attribute:

```
<div row-index="0" style="height: 47px; transform: translateY(0px);">aaa</div>
<div row-index="1" style="height: 47px; transform: translateY(0px);">bbb</div>
<div row-index="3" style="height: 47px; transform: translateY(0px);">ccc</div>
```

I have tried this code, that doesn't work:

```
cy.get('div[@row-index]').should('have.length', 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also directly use `row-index` for this:

```js
cy.get('[row-index]').should('have.length', 3);
```

Another way to assert length:

```js
cy.get('[row-index]').its('length').should('eq', 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

It should work without the '@'

```js
cy.get('div[row-index]').should('have.length', 3);
```